# TextField with Keyboard in cocos2d !

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to develop a iphone app by using cocos2d. I create a alert view with a text field. when I touch the text field then comes the keyboard. But I want that when the alert is open, in the same time textfield will be selected and keyboard comes(without any touch). how can it posible ? sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[myTextField becomeFirstResponder] will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a little tricky to do. The controls in iPhone use the concept of "first responders" Any events will be handled by the first responder in the controller. Now, when an alert view is displayed, it becomes the first responder so it can respond to button clicks. When a text field is selected by the user, the keyboard gets the control. So I guess what you want to achieve can be done by making the text field the first responder after showing the alert ([txtField becomeFirstResponder])

But I have no idea how the alert view's responses will be handled then. You won't be able to click the OK button on the alert view till the keyboard is dismissed and you resign the first responder of the text field. ([txtField resignFirstResponder]) (This is just a guess, you will have to check the final behavior)

Answer (score 0):

[myTextField becomeFirstResponder] works -- I tested it.